# Probability of values in a $K \times K$ with different probability for each value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a $K \times K$ table and N discs with 1 written on them and $K^2-N$ discs with 0 written on them, it is known that $K< N < K^2-N$ and $N/K=L\in\mathbb{N}$. The discs are randomly distributed between the table cells (1 disc per cell). I need to calculate the probability that:

1. Each row has the exact same sum of digits
2. At least 1 row's digits sum is 3 (assuming $K > 3$)
3. At least 1 row's digits sum is K

for (1) I calculated the probability by $$P_1=\frac{\binom{N}{L,L,...,L}\cdot \binom{K^2-N}{K-L,K-L,...,K-L}}{\binom{K^2}{K,K,...,K}}$$
for (2) I'm not really sure but the first thing I tried is, I have $\binom{N}{3}$ ways to choose 3 discs with 1, $\binom{K^2-N}{K-3}$ ways to choose the remaining discs in the row and $\binom{K^2}{K}$ ways to choose discs in a row so $$P_2=\frac{\binom{N}{3}\cdot \binom{K^2-N}{K-3}}{\binom{K^2}{K}}$$ the same for (3) which means $$P_3=\frac{\binom{N}{K}\cdot \binom{K^2-N}{0}}{\binom{K^2}{K}}=\frac{\binom{N}{K}\cdot 1}{\binom{K^2}{K}}$$ but these ((2) & (3)) are wrong as I found out using a script (and choosing fitting K and N). I thought maybe using the same method as I used in (1) but there are too many ways to distribute the discs between the K rows for it to be practical

---

EDIT: I might have found a way to calculate (3) but it feels pretty far fetched: I have $\binom{K^2}{N}$ ways to choose cells that have a disc with the digit 1, and let's say I choose 1 row to have $K$ of those discs, I have $K$ ways to choose that row, as for the remaining $N-K$ disks I have $K^2 - K$ cells to distribute them to, which can be done in $\binom{K^2 - K}{N-K}$ thus $$P_3=\frac{K\cdot \binom{K^2 - K}{N-K}}{\binom{K^2}{N}}$$

Comment: Is a line a row, a column, a diagonal, any of those?

Comment: It is a row, I'll edit this